# Fastest Way to Iterate Over Dataframe Column to Find Match in Strings

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a very truncated extract from a large dataframe:

| name | age | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ben | 66 | NY |
| rob | 45 | LON |
| james | 22 | LA |

I also have a numerous strings that each contain different words but will contain one (not more) of the values in the name column.

For example:

1. "rob was born in London"
2. "ben once lived in New York"

For each string I want to iterate over the "name" column to find the name that matches the name in the string and return the age of the person.

So in the first example the desired result is 45 and in the second example the desired result is 66.

I am new to Pandas and am struggling. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Data*

```
s = pd.Series(['rob was born in London', "ben once lived in New York"])
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ben', 'rob', 'james'],
                    'age': [66, 45, 22],
                    'city': ['NY', 'LON', 'LA']})
```

*Solution*

```
who = s.str.extract('(' + ')|('.join(df.name) + ')').bfill(axis=1)[0]
age_by_name = dict(zip(df.name, df.age))
pd.DataFrame({'text': s, 'age': who.map(age_by_name)})


                      text  age
0   rob was born in London  45
1   ben once lived in New York  66
```

*Explanation*

Use `.str.extract` to get the name in the string and then match it with the dataframe to get the age.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

List of all strings. This can be part of another dataframe. Just select the column where this values are & convert it to list.

```
l = ['rob was born in London', "ben once lived in New York"]
```

The dataframe from your example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ben', 'rob', 'james'],
                    'age': [66, 45, 22],
                    'city': ['NY', 'LON', 'LA']})
```

Final dataset where `string` & `age` exist.

```
age_dat = pd.DataFrame()
```

The first for-loop, loops over names from your original (`df`) dataset. The second for-loop loops over list of `sentences` (list `l`). If any name is found in `l`, it gets appended in `age_dat`.

```
for x in list(df.name):
   
    for z in l:
        if x in z:
            dat = pd.DataFrame()
            dat['string']=[z]
            dat['age'] = [df[df['name']==x].age.tolist()[0]]
       
            age_dat = age_dat.append(dat)

print(age_dat)



                          string  age
0  ben once lived in New York   66
0      rob was born in London   45
```